# Upgraded to Marshmallow, now I can't merge my conversations in Hangouts

Tags: sms, gmail, google-hangouts, instant-messaging

I have a 2014 VZW Moto X that I recently unlocked the bootloader on. So I upgraded to CM 13. Previously, when I was on Lolipop I used Hangouts as my default texting app. The majority of people I was talking to from within Hangouts was over SMS, but a a few Google Chat conversations were in there too. I was always able to send and SMS from my phone number to any other phone number.

Now, on Marshmallow, it seems I need to switch over to my "SMS" profile in order to see my texts and to send texts via my carrier number, and to see my Google Chats conversations I have to switch over to my gmail account. The account switching it all from within Hangouts, at the top of the sidebar. Also, to access the Hangouts dialer I need to be switched over to my gmail account. This was never the case before. I think back on Lolipop I was always signed in as my gmail account, so I had access to the dialer, google chats, but also my carrier SMS messages.

I have "Merged Conversations" enabled, and Hangouts is my default texting application. Is there some way I can get back to how I was using Hangouts before? With all my SMS and Google Chat messages in one list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as soon as a I post this I figure out the answer.

I ahd to go into my SMS settings from within Hangouts and change the "Default SMS messaging account" to my gmail and "Send SMS from" to my carrier number.

Now there are no longer two accounts to switch between in the menu, and all my Google Chat and text messages are in one list. I also have to ability to switch over to the dialer.